# PostgreSQL RIGHT JOIN ERROR: syntax error at or near "RIGHT"

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Please tell me what is wrong with that sql ?

```
SELECT users_map.user_id 
FROM users_map
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1
AND users_map.service_user_id = 0
RIGHT OUTER JOIN user_data
ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE` clause should be placed at the end of your query:

```
SELECT users_map.user_id 
FROM users_map
RIGHT OUTER JOIN user_data
  ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1 AND 
      users_map.service_user_id = 0
```

Comment: Thanks now it works correct but the result was not what i expected. In user_date there is a column named alternative_mail fom which i want to take these entries which have this - 
 ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1 AND 
      users_map.service_user_id = 0

Comment: @RockOrDead Use `LEFT JOIN` and specify `user_data` in `FROM`